# X-editable Datepicker + Bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I am looking at X-editable what looks pretty cool but I am not sure if it is being updated anymore(Nov 2013 was last update).

It apparently does not support the date picker option. I am wondering if anyone knows of an alternative to X-editable or a fork that has a working date picker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for date picker. This is really nice and can also have TIME picker if you want. And is working in all the browsers including IE.

Comment: Did you manage to integrate this datetimepicker with x-editable?